# Perform action only when button is held

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I make a `Button` which executes the code under it only when the `Button` is pressed and held (let's say for one second) and stops when it is released?

Comment: there should be a Hold event on the buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use any timers. The [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.button%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class contains an event for [Hold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.hold%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

You can use it like this:

```
<Button Hold="eventHandler"/>
```

Touch Input guide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207076%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Timer` like this:

```
private void button1_MouseLeftDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   timer1.Enabled = true;
   timer1.Start();
}

private void button1_MouseLeftDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   timer1.Stop();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Do your job
}
```

But the best way is the `Hold` event.

Answer (score 0):

Button has a boolean `IsPressed` property which you can check; it is true when it's pressed down, false otherwise.

Also you can use several events. One way is to use `TouchDown` event, which triggers when you click on element via touch. And `TouchUp` triggers when the finger is lifted from the button.

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).